# Should I consider the contribution of a variable in correspondance analysis if the $cos^2$ is weak?

Tags: correlation, contingency-tables, correspondence-analysis, cosine-similarity, cosine-distance

So I have this table that represents contribution and cosinus of variable in CA

[image]

I noticed that the most popular choice ( 1-5 hours ) has the weakest contributions and the weakest cosinus.

It made sense that it has the weakest contribution because the two new axis are independant but should I even look at the contribution if the cos2 is weak ( cos2 indicates how well represented the variable is ).

In retrospect, does contribution make any sense of the cos2 is insignificant?